# How can I group exact string together?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working with a google sheet that contains a column of unique project numbers followed by a column with the equipment description used in that project. I have set up my code to send an automatic email with this information to a list of recipients. What I want to do that I don't know how to is what code can I use that will read the project number column and when it finds two project numbers exactly the same, it will group the equipment together into a list that will be sent in that automatic email. I know the list can be a variable but I just don't know how to make it look for spa project numbers to join the equipment together without changing anything in the google sheet. Thank y'all!

Comment: That's called a pivot table.  I use objects to build them in scripts.  Are you comfortable using objects?

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with Cooper. To build an object is a most obvious way to get unique values (ID, etc) from any list:

```js
var data = [
    [1,'a'],
    [2,'b'],
    [3,'c'],
    [1,'d']
]

var obj = {};

data.forEach(x => {
  try { obj[x[0]].push(x[1]) }    // try to add the value to an existed array
  catch(e) { obj[x[0]] = [x[1]] } // or make an array if there is no existed one
});

console.log(obj); // out: [ {1:[a,d]}, {2:[b]}, {3:[c]} ]

var id = 1
console.log('All the values from ID '+ id + ': ' + obj[id].join(', ')); // out: a, d
```